# History of Gamma and Beta functions

Tags: special-functions, book-recommendation, gamma-function, beta-function

I'm looking for a book on the history of gamma $\Gamma$ and beta $B$ functions!
thank you in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site.

Comment: There are a coupe of pages on the history of the gamma function in a "historical note" in *Functions of a Real Variable* by Bourbaki. I'm not sure if that will be enough to address your needs. It's funny that Bourbaki thought that was on-topic in a rigorous math treatise, while people say it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any books, but here is an article on this topic:

Davis, P.J.: Leonard Euler’s integral: a historical profile of the Gamma function. Am. Math. Mon. 66, 849–869 (1959)